# Service intent must be explicit : Has Extras

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have tried different things but unsure what is going wrong, I get this error when I start this specific service.

> Service intent must be explicit:  Intent {
>   act=com.xamarin.action.PLAY(has extras) }

I am passing a string `ID` when starting the service as following

```
var intent = new Intent(MediaService.ActionPlay);
intent.PutExtra("ID", ID);                                
StartService(intent); // Error here
```

My service looks something like the following

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { ActionPlay, ActionPause, ActionStop })]
public class MediaService: Service
  {
   public const string ActionPlay = "com.xamarin.action.PLAY";
   public const string ActionPause = "com.xamarin.action.PAUSE";
   public const string ActionStop = "com.xamarin.action.STOP";

   public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, 
     StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
     { 
       switch (intent.Action)
                {
                    case ActionPlay: Play(intent.GetStringExtra("ID")); break;
                    case ActionStop: Stop(); break;
                    case ActionPause: Pause(); break;
                }
     }     
  }
```

Where the play action is the following

```
public bool Play(string playID)
{ 
   ....
}
```

What am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the package id of your intent:

```
intent.SetPackage(PackageName);
```

Or use the current context and the Java class (or C# type):

```
var intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MediaService));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I used the current context and C# type along with `intent.SetAction("com.xamarin.action.PLAY");` and it is working now. Highly appreciate your help. Cheers

Comment: Glad I could help 